# how to generate a warning on type conversion like ( int32 < int64)

Tags: gcc, type-conversion, clang

I know gcc an show warning a type truncate, but I don't know how to show warning in compare:

```
int32 a;
int64 b;
a = b;  // gcc can show warnings with 'Wconversion'
a < b  //gcc will not show any warnings

//this case may dead loop
for ( a = 0;  a< b; a++)
```

Comment: Read your C/C++ standards. The int32 will be promoted to int64 in both of those comparisons.  There might be a lint like setting that can warn on the for loop case, but it wouldn't make sense anywhere else.

Comment: Yes I just want a warning in loop case, is there any parameters in gcc?